# Vue Jest Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have a component as below:

```
<template>
   <h1>{{ numberOfRecords }}</h1>
   <button @click="callMe">Update</Button>
</template>

<script>
import MyService from '../services/MyService'
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

  data() {
    return {
      numberOfRecords: 0,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async callMe() {
        try {
          console.log('calling post')
          const myResponse = await MyService.postSomething(this.data)
          this.numberOfRecords = bulkUpdateResponse.data.numberOfRecords
        } catch (error) {
          const message = error.response ? error.response.data : error
          console.log(message)
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

`MyService.js` is like:

```
import AxiosService from './AxiosService'

const resourceUrl = 'rest/myrestpath'

export default {
  postSomething(data) {
    return AxiosService.post(`${resourceUrl}/somepath`, data)
  },
}
```

Finally, `AxiosService` is where `axios` post happens.

I want to write unit test for `MyComponent` where in I want to mock `MyService.postSomething` to return mock data and avoid axios call.

My `MyComponent.spec.js` looks like:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from '../../src/views/MyComponent.vue'
import MyService from '../../src/services/MyService.js'

jest.mock('../../src/services/MyService')

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods
      MyService.postSomething.mockClear()
    })

it('We get a success', () => {
    const resp = { data: { numberOfRecords: '10' } }
    MyService.postSomething.mockImplementation(() => resp)

    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent)

    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.numberOfRecords).toBe(10)  // why not updated ?

    wrapper.vm.$nextTick().then(() => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.$data.numberOfRecords).toBe(10)  // still not updating. getting error.
    }
   })
  })
})
```

On running this test, I am expecting `numberOfRecords` to be updated to `10` as per my mock json. However, that does not happen where my first `expect` statement is.

I then thought I have to put it inside `$nextTick()`, however, it still doesn't work. I get the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15964) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am new to Vue and Jest. I am having difficulty in understanding what is going wrong here and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data isn't expected to be updated immediately after `trigger('click')`, this is what `$nextTick` is for. Additionally, it isn't expected to be 10 number because it's set to '10' string. `expect` would provide useful feedback on this if there were correct error output from failed test.

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` appears because there is unhandled promise rejection, it doesn't cause a test to fail.  `then(...)` promise wasn't chained to return a rejected promise from test function. The most simple way to not leave it unchained is `async..await` syntax:

```
it('We get a success', async () => {
    ...
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.numberOfRecords).toBe('10')
})
```

If `numberOfRecords` is supposed to be a number and used for mathematical operations, it should be forced to be a number, either in JSON response or in the place where it's processed:

```
this.numberOfRecords = +bulkUpdateResponse.data.numberOfRecords
```